# I go hashids.c/hashids.h file not found error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, hashids

I use `hashids` library in my project and I want hashing my integer number. but when I adding `NNLHashids.h` & `NNLHashids.m` in my project I got this error ....

please guide me about that.!!!

Comment: where is the error ?

Comment: this error showing in NNLHashids.m file @psyco